# What's the best way to support the "ROLE_" prefix for Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security, legacy-app

If you are supporting an older application that does not have prefixes on all the roles, what is the best way to support the "ROLE_" prefix? Is there a way to ignore or omit it from loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to ignore the prefix within the normal spring security configuration. However, I found that you can easily append "ROLE_" to all your roles when loading from the database. I just use the CONCAT function within MySQL to add "ROLE_" to all roles. See below:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, CONCAT('ROLE_', rolename) as authority FROM user_role WHERE active = 1 AND username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, active FROM user WHERE username = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This concept can also be applied if you create your own class using the UserDetailsService interface:

```
<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="com.my.security.MyPasswordEncoder" />
```

NOTE: I use an "alias" for the "authentication-manager" instead of an ID, because my customization seems to be ignored during the authentication process if I override the default ID.